# How can I call a generic method on an injected class without informing the parent class of the generic type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface, dependency-injection

Below is the implementation of a dependency that is injected into another class.

```
public class CsvDataProvider : ICsvDataProvider
{
    readonly ICsvReaderFactory _factory;

    public CsvDataProvider(ICsvReaderFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public IEnumerable<TRecord> GetData<TRecord>(string filepath) where TRecord : class
    {
        var reader = _factory.CreateCsvReader(filepath);

        return reader.GetRecords<TRecord>();
    }
}
```

The `reader` that is created by the `factory` will read all lines in a CSV file and convert each line to an instance of `TRecord`. I do not own the `reader` code and can not change the `GetRecords<TRecord>()` method.

This is where I am stuck:

```
public class CsvDataMigrationController
{
    readonly ICsvDataProvider _provider;
    readonly ICsvDataMigration _migration;

    public CsvDataMigrationController(ICsvDataProvider provider, ICsvDataMigration migration)
    {
        _provider = provider;
        _migration = migration;
    }

    public void ProcessFile(string path)
    {
        var records = _provider.GetData<I_DONT_WANT_TO_EXPLICITLY_SAY>(path); //<-- Help!

        _migration.Migrate(records);
    }
}
```

The intent is to inject a data provider and a migration procedure class into `CsvDataMigrationController`. The controller would call the data provider to get the data and pass the data into the migration class.

- I don't want the `CsvDataMigrationController` to know about the type of data involved.
- I don't want the `CsvDataProvider` to know about the migration.
- I don't want the `CsvDataMigration` to know about where the data came from.

Any advice on how I can achieve this?

Note: I did not include the `CsvDataMigration` class because I didn't think it was useful in the explanation, but will include it if needed.

Comment: What type does `Migrate()` accept? `IEnumerable<object>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since you can't change `GetRecords`, then perhaps the most straightforward way is to ask the migration interface for the record type, and use reflection to call the generic `GetData` method with that runtime-obtained type. Something like:

```
public void ProcessFile(string path)
{
    Type recordType = _migration.InputRecordType;

    var getDataMethod =
        _provider.GetType()
        .GetMethod("GetData")
        .MakeGenericMethod(recordType);

    var records = getDataMethod.Invoke(_provider, new object[] { path });
    _migration.Migrate(records);
}
```

Comment: +1 I was about to present this as an alternate solution in my answer but you beat me to it.

Comment: This may work well because for each entity type there is also a specific CsvDataMigration class. I cringe a bit at .GetMethod("GetData"), but it's a step forward. I'm going to think this over a bit, but as it stands, this is the approach I'm taking for now. Thanks!

Comment: @jkappers: No problem :-) Reflection is generally messy, but it solves a whole class of problems very easily.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, you will define a non-generic alternative such as

```
public interface ICsvDataProvider
{
    IEnumerable GetData(string filepath, Type recordType) 

    IEnumerable<TRecord> GetData<TRecord>(string filepath) 
        where TRecord : class;
}
```

So you could call this as

```
public class CsvDataMigrationController
{
    private string targetTypeName = ...;

    public void ProcessFile(string path)
    {
        var recordType = Type.GetType(this.targetTypeName);
        var records = _provider.GetData(path, recordType);
        _migration.Migrate(records);
    }
}
```

In this way, the generic method is just a bit of syntactic sugar around the non-generic method.

Using reflection (as in @Cameron's answer) is another solution. In both cases you must know the target type at run time (rather than at compile time as the generic method requires).

Comment: +1, it seems we independently arrived at fairly similar answers ;-)

Comment: I had considered making specific implementations of CsvDataMigration but decided against it because this class would always do the same thing, regardless of type of entity I'm dealing with. 

Currently, I only have specific concrete types of CsvDataMigration, since the procedural code is significantly different for each entity type.

Thanks for this answer.

Comment: +1 because it answers my question, even though it wasn't the implementation I went with.